# Reduced scheme and covering with non affines reduced schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For a scheme $X$ to be reduced there is a criterion that says that $X$ is reduced if there is a covering $(U_i)$ by **affines** open subsets such that for all $i$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is reduced. I guess that it doesn't works anymore when the $U_i$ are not affines. Does someone has a example.

I tried with the classical $\operatorname{Spec}(k[X]/(X^2))$ but all its open sets are affine... something like $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(x^2)$ maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $X$ is an open cover of itself, it suffices to find a nonreduced scheme $X$ with reduced ring of global sections - this will imply that reducedness cannot be checked on global sections of an arbitrary cover. The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989158/a-particular-example-of-a-non-reduced-scheme-with-a-reduced-ring-of-global-sect) should be an example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stahl says it suffices to have some non reduced scheme $X$ with global sections ring $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ non reduce. The example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889949/global-sections-on-non-reduced-proejctive-schemes) is perfect: $X=\operatorname{Proj}k[s,x_0,x_1]/(s^2)$ is not reduce because with
$$U=D_+(x_0)=\operatorname{Spec}\left(k\left(\frac{s}{x_0},\frac{x_1}{x_0}\right)/\left(\left(\frac{s}{x_0}\right)^2\right)\right)$$
one has $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ not reduced but the global sections ring $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is reduced because 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(X)=k$$
se the link above.